# pypyodbc error Invalid object name for a temp table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

Receiving the error **pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#responses_to_dedupe'.")** when trying to query a temporary table.  My actual queries are a bit more complex, but here's the boiled down version that gets the same result:

```
c.execute("""
    SELECT ECR_ID, RespondentID, ? AS DestinationID, 
        TEIQuestionID, DateSubmitted
    INTO #responses_to_dedupe
    FROM ETLTEIConsumerResponses
    WHERE DoNotProcess IS NULL;
    """, [source['destinationid']])

c.execute("""
    SELECT *
    FROM #responses_to_dedupe;
    """)
```

(Note that the traceback before the error message shows the offense occurring on the last line of the above code block -- """) -- not on the first of the two execute(), so I am assuming that it created the table just fine.)

I've been doing the exact same thing for years in a production script on the same machine/environment without the error and even create another temp table earlier in this script and access it without incidence.  The only difference from those 2 situations is that the temp table is named using camel case -- this one I went all lower case with underscores.  But still get the same result if I change the name of the table to #ResponsesToDedupe.

I have also tried a c.commit() statement between the two, but same result.

Comment: I don't know Python, however, a temporary table only persists for the duration of the connection that created it. Looking at your code sample, I would guess those are 2 separate connections, and so the table doesn't exists when the second command is run.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @user3469050 as far of sql is correct. You should be able able to put both statements into one execute statement

```
c.execute("""
    WITH responses_to_dedupe_cte
AS
(
    SELECT ECR_ID, RespondentID, ? AS DestinationID, 
        TEIQuestionID, DateSubmitted
    FROM ETLTEIConsumerResponses
    WHERE DoNotProcess IS NULL
) 
SELECT *    FROM responses_to_dedupe_cte
""", [source['destinationid']])
```

Otherwise, you can use a global temp table but I generally shy away from that.

```
##responses_to_dedupe
```